# How do I uninstall Windows XP from my NTFS if I have Ubuntu installed there as well

Tags: installation, partitioning, windows, uninstall, ntfs

Hello I installed Ubuntu 13.10 alongside Windows XP, Now that I never use Windows XP and I have almost no space for Ubuntu (I literally only have 136mb left) I would like to uninstall it from my NTFS and reallocate the remaining space on my NTFS drive to Ubuntu without damaging my Ubuntu installation.

Comment: No, Ubuntu and windows are installed on the same drive, My NTFS drive

Comment: Did you use Wubi to install Ubuntu?

Comment: Drive is not equal to partition. I think the terminology may be causing some confusion.

Comment: Ok I have deleted the windows partition but now I need help merging the unallocated space with my current installation and making ubuntu boot on startup. http://askubuntu.com/questions/372212/how-do-i-add-the-unallocated-space-to-my-ubuntu-installation-after-deleting-the

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all , your XP and Ubuntu are not on the same NTFS drive!!! They can't be!
Ubuntu is using ext4.

An easy and secure way of doing this is :- 
Make sure all drives are unmounted(easiest by going in live ubuntu CD)

Then open up Gparted , locate your NTFS drive , delete it and create a new ext4 partition or merge it with your existing one.

If you can't use Gparted , then I recommend `cfdisk` its a terminal based utility with nice GUI like interface but very powerful.

Comment: It may be correct that they are on the same drive, I think you meant partition.

Comment: You are differentiating b/w drive and partition.
And I'm differentiating b/w hard disk and internal drives.

Comment: I will try this