# How do I add the unallocated space to my ubuntu installation after deleting the Windows XP Partition?

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning, 13.10, live-cd

I just deleted the Windows XP partition in the Ubuntu Live CD because I don't use windows xp anymore, now I have this [image: Screenie]

I want to add the remaining space to my ubuntu installation and make ubuntu boot on startup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I can see your partition map correctly, first you have to resize your extended partion to include the free space.

After that you can extend /dev/sda5.

You can only do this when Linux on /dev/sda5 is not active. So, you have to do this from another running operating system. A possible solution is to use a Linux Live CD, such as Ubuntu or Knoppix. Summarized

1. Download a Linux Live CD
2. Burn it to CD or write it to a USB memory key
3. Boot Linux Live from CD or USB
4. Start gparted from Linux Live
5. Resize your extended partition
6. Resize your Linux partition /dev/sda5
7. Reboot

Does this answer your question?

Comment: You should mention to make a backup first!

Comment: Thanks this is the answer I was looking for but I kinda figured it out before I checked askubuntu, Thanks for helping though!

Answer (score -1):

I made a backup and I swapped off my linux-swap because I couldn't resize my partition, after I did that I used the boot repair and now my computer works like a charm!

Comment: This does tell what you did, but in reality it doesn't give an answer on "how to do it".